# Detect end of Deflate stream in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, zip, deflate

When reading a stream of bytes that contains a Deflate stream, is it possible to detect where the Delfate stream ends? If so: how? (Ideally in Python).

I see [Decompress.unused_data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.Decompress.unused_data), that looks like it could be involved, but I'm not quite sure how to use it.

Context: writing a streaming unZIP implementation where the compressed data size, i.e. the size of the Deflate stream of each compressed file is not always known up-front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is to decode the entire deflate stream. The deflate format is self-terminating, so it tells you when it ends. There is no magic sequence of bits or bytes that you can search for to find the end.

Indeed, in Python you would use `decompressobj` in the zlib module to do this, checking `unused_data` until it is non-empty. When it is, the deflate stream terminated at the byte before what was returned by `unused_data`.